# What is the scope/persistence of an object activated by a triggered function in Google Spreadsheet API?

Tags: scope, google-sheets-api, active-objects

Google Spreadsheet API has various methods for setting the active Spreadsheet, Sheet, Range, column, and so forth, programmatically. These methods can be used from triggered scripts that run when the UI isn't open. However, I don't see any documentation explaining how long this activation persists.

Experience and intuition suggests that when, say, a spreadsheet is activated programmatically, it is "active" in the global scope, and will stay active until the original function call ends. However, I am afraid I will be surprised by some edge case if this is not exactly right.

For example, if I have a bound script that is triggered to run on Friday, and it calls another bound script which activates a spreadsheet, it seems that the spreadsheet remains active after that second script closes, and another script call can still "getActiveSpreadsheet". However, if the triggered script terminates, and another script is triggered 5 minutes later, you would have to activate it by ID again.

Is there any documentation, or is my understanding complete?

As an example, consider a case where one Google Service's API is triggered by the result of a change caused by a triggered function in a separate service.

Answer (score 0):

> [*getActiveSpreadsheet()*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet)
>
> Gets the active sheet in a spreadsheet. The active sheet in a spreadsheet is the sheet that is being displayed in the spreadsheet UI.

It is not discussed in the document on how long the document is active or could remain active. But it is written as long as it is being displayed in the spreadsheet UI it is the active sheet.

Comment: I'm more interested in persistence when a sheet is activated programmatically, eg with a .Activate() call, when the UI isn't open at all.

Comment: I think the logic would still be the same even when a sheet is activated using a function.

Comment: Sorry, I guess it wasn't clear that I'm referring to triggered functions. I have a function that runs every week at Midnight, when my computer is off. No UI is open, so the answer I'm looking for cannot involve anything being displayed in the UI.

Comment: You can use openById(), no UI needed and it is more accurate than using .Active call.

Comment: Okay, so same question. If I "open" something by ID, what is the scope/persistence of the open object, for when I want to .getActive(Object)?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "more accurate"?

Comment: By persistence in openID(), until the triggered script ends but then again there is no document to how long is the scope/persistence of the open object. By accurate meaning I am opening the spreadsheet file by it's unique ID. It may depend on how or what function we are used to or comfortable using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106197/discussion-between-mr-rebot-and-dr-queso).

Comment: A good answer to my question has relevance and value to other people, so I would prefer to have your answer here rather than in private chat. I don't consider this an extended discussion; all of these comments have been dedicated to clarifying my original question (I leave it up to others to determine whether my question is unclear, or whether the problem is elsewhere.)